# Add field in general section in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Below is my snippet of code:

```
function general_e_field_add_kora(){

add_settings_field('header_text','Header Text','general_field','general');

register_setting('general','header_text');  
}add_action('admin_init','general_e_field_add_kora');

function general_field(){

echo "<h1>This is a heading </h1>" ;
}
```

What is wrong with that code? im getting the below warning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnTSQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code working fine. please check line number `11`. its end with `;` correctly?

```
function general_e_field_add_kora(){
add_settings_field('header_text','Header Text','general_field','general');
    register_setting('general','header_text');  
}

add_action('admin_init','general_e_field_add_kora');

function general_field(){
    echo "<h1>This is a heading </h1>" ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You got the culprit, though u didnt see my the previous line, but , Yes, i missed a semicolon, before the function declaration. Thanks again.